# How to refresh the image content in a window?

Tags: image, opencv

```
cv2.namedWindow("image",0)
img=cv2.imread("autojump.png")
while 1:
    img=cv2.imread("autojump.png")
    cv2.imshow("image",img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(0) & 0XFF
    if k== 27 :
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The image file `autojump.png`'s content will change along with time(rewritten by

`with open("autojump.png","w") as f : 
f.write(some_other_image_bytes_stream)`
), so I reload it during the while loop, but it seems that the window never refresh.Just always the same image. What's wrong?

Comment: This `autojump.png` file changes because it is from the screenshot of my Android phone.When you do something,your screenshot will certainly change.

Answer (score 0):

waitKey(0) will wait until you press a key. Change to waitKey(1) to stop waiting after at least 1 ms and loading and displaying the image continuously without any further interaction required.

Increase to waitKey(N) if you want to wait at least N ms to not use too much processing time all the time but if it is ok for you to get a delay of about N/2 between new image capture and window refresh.